# Cannot Produce Contour Outlining on Pgothic Text

Tags: fonts, pdftex, contour, scalerel, pgothic

I compile the following code with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgothic}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage{pdfrender}      
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
\contourlength{1.35pt}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\definecolor{forestgreen}{rgb}{.13, .55, .13}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge
{\pgothfamily{\contour{black}{\scalefont{1.55}{\color{forestgreen!55!black}\textbf{The New York Times}}}}}

\vspace*{35pt}

\cabin
\contour{black}{{\scalefont{1.50}{\color{forestgreen!55!black}\textbf{NEWSPAPER}}}}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, there is not outlining of the `pgothic` text; whereas, the contour outlining the non-pgothic text seems to be working fine.

Does anyone why the `contour` command does not work in the MWE when using the `pgothic` font? I have tried placing the `contour` command in other places, but to no avail. Also, although I did not make it part of the MWE, I have not been able to produce contour outlining with any font when I try to "stretch" the letters with the `vstretch` command. Is there a known clash between the `contour` and `[outline]scalerel` packages?

Comment: the documentation is only four pages long and on the second page it mentions "Outline (vector) fonts have to be used." and also the package option needed if you use metafont fonts.

Comment: When I run the code I do get a contour around the first line, i.e., I can't reproduce the problem (using pdflatex from TeX Live 2019).

Comment: The `copies` option also works (`\usepackage[copies]{contour}`) and looks a bit better even than the `outline` option imo.